# AngularJS: get promise value without internal properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, ngresource

Ok, another promise-related question (I see there are already quite a few of them). I'm trying to get promise result from endpoint and use it in ng-repeat, first is the typical response from endpoint:

```
{"ebbe5704-4ea5-470e-8ab9-102ee8ca457f":"Foo",
 "e380a6f7-2f88-46bb-bd54-251719353627":"Bar"
}
```

here's how I get it from promise:

```
RequestService.getValues().$promise.then(function(res) {
    vm.result = res;
});
```

and here I render it in HTML:

```
<p ng-repeat="i in vm.result">{{i}}</p>
```

The problem is the rendered view contains internal fields of the promise (`$promise` and `$resolved`):
[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any less ugly way instead of filtering through result keys?

UPD:
`RequestService.getValues` is a `$resource`, so can be replaced like this:

```
$resource("/rest/", null, {
    getValues: {
        url: "/rest/values/",
        method: "GET"
    }
}).getValues().$promise.then(function(res) {
    vm.result = res;
    console.log("RES:", res);
});
```

Comment: Can you paste your `RequestService.getValues` function?

Comment: @MathewBerg thanks, I updated the question with the code of resource declaration

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are iterating with `ng-repeat` over an object (so getting the keys of each property of the object) and not over an array.

AngularJS resources are made to be used with `ng-repeat` only if the returned resource is an array. 
When facing an object `ng-repeat` uses something like `for(var key in obj)` whereas when facing an array it uses the indexer to loop as following `for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)`. Thus, with an array, it is skipping other properties like `$promise` and so.

What you should do is implement a custom filter that will skip angular decorators methods away from the `ng-repeat` iteration:

```
$scope.skipResourceFn= function(key)
{
    // is it an angular decorator (starting with '$' char):
    return key.indexOf('$') != 0;
};
```

Then in your template:

```
<p ng-repeat="i in vm.result | filter:skipResourceFn">{{i}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use the `$http` service to get the object:

```
var config = {
    url: "/rest/values/",
    method: "GET"
};

$http(config).then(function(response) {
    var data = response.data;
    vm.result = data;
    console.log("RES:", data);
});
```

The $http service does not append additional properties to an object.